# Рисовалка + 3d модель на js

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, html5, canvas, 3d

Здравствуйте! Хотелось бы спросить совета. Задача такова: у нас есть 3d модель, допустим цилиндр, и развёртка этой модели.То есть одно окно с моделью, а другое окно это графический редактор. Нужно, чтобы при изменении в графическом редакторе сразу менялись текстуры на 3d модели. Подскажите, как это лучше реализовывать и что использовать.Стоит задача сделать это всё в браузере.

Comment: three.js там все есть

Comment: А можно немного поконкретней, что нужно использовать. Возможно ли там рисовалку сделать и вгружать в эту рисовалку картинки.Это же 3д движок

Comment: да там можно все что связано с 3d и webgl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно ты искал что то такое

```
<p class="f"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.jeremieboulay.fr">@Jeremboo</a><br />┗|｀O´|┛</p>
```

[Threejs-texture-tool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/threejs-texture-tool)

https://codepen.io/Jeremboo/pen/qqabKY?q=threejs%20texture&limit=all&order=popularity&depth=everything&show_forks=false